# covariance matrix to correlation matrix and conversely (if we have deviation vector)

Tags: linear-algebra, statistics, matrix-calculus, covariance, correlation

hey what's the formula for a covariance matrix if i have a given collation matrix and standard deviation vector? And in the other direction what is the formula for the correlation matrix if I have a given covariance matrix and the standard deviation vector?

Comment: Denote the $\{$covariance, std deviation, correlation$\}$ matrices by
$\{C,V,R\}$ respectively, then
$$\eqalign{
V &= {\rm Diag}(v) \\
R &= V^{-1}CV^{-1} \\
C &= VRV \\
}$$

Comment: Thank youuuuuuu